# Having trouble understanding USB 2.0 industrial camera bandwidth

Tags: usb, bandwidth, camera

I'm using an IDS uEye industrial camera like [this one](https://es.ids-imaging.com/store/ui-1240se.html). It basically records 1280 x 1024 at 23 fps (4 channels of 8 bits). As a result of some possible usb power/bandwidth problems, I was trying to calculate the required camera's bandwith. so I did this:

1280 * 1024 * 23 * 4 * 8 / (8 * 10^6) = ~120 MiB/s = ~115 MB/s

I confirmed this by checking a captured bmp image's size: around 5 MB, so at 23 fps it gives us 5*23 = 115 MB/s. To clarify, I'm not recording a video stream, but separate frames.

Then I realized this is an USB 2.0 camera, so there is a limit of 60 MB/s. Even the camera documentation says:

> *"Theoretically, up to 50 MByte/s of data can be transmitted in this mode, but in practice, this value is hardly ever reached. A
> high-performance desktop PC can transmit about 40 MByte/s, most
> notebooks or embedded PC systems even less than that."*

So I started to think there's something I'm missing. I used [usbtop](https://github.com/aguinet/usbtop) to monitor the USB bandwith, and I got a value of ~4 MiB/s. So, how is it possible that the camera is capturing 115 MB of images per second while running on a USB 2.0 bus and consuming only 4 MB/s? Is it some kind of compression?

Comment: @sawdust I thought these kind of cameras avoided compression. Are the images, once stored on the hard drive, decompressed again? Because I fail to grasp how, if they are being compressed, they take 115MB/s on the drive. And we're talking about a 30 to 1 compression here, if my math is correct.

Comment: @sawdust Just to clarify, as i didnt mentioned it: I'm not recording video but separate frames, one by one, in what IDS calls "freerun" mode.

Comment: I incorrectly assumed that a "camera" with a USB interface was a video camera.  It turns out that you have a "camera" that is an image sensor.  Image sensors typically have a parallel data interface that transmit raw image data.  The datasheet for that camera has zero information about the interface and what USB drivers are required to use that camera.  Without any information, I retract what I previously wrote as I don't know what applies..

Comment: @sawdust Yes, there is little to none information. Even with a parallel data interface, you shouldn’t be able to exceed the usb 2.0 specification bandwidth, rigjt? How does parallelization help in those cases?

Comment: A parallel interface can transfer N bits at a time, whereas serial interfaces such as RS-232 and USB transfer 1 bit at a time.  The issue with a parallel interface is that you now have N data lines that have to be synchronized, and that gets tricky as the transfer rate and/or distance are increased.  Hence the trend from parallel to serial interfaces: IDE to SATA, Centronics to USB, PCI to PCIe.

Comment: The typical (low-cost) image sensor  may have a data interface of 8 to 12 bits.  I use SoCs (computer system on a chip) that have an image sensor controller that handle up-to-12-bit transfers.   No doubt your camera has a SoC built-in, since its exposed USB interface requires a (micro)processor to handle the USB protocol on its end.  With today's level of integration, such a "camera" could compress, encode and even encrypt the image sensor data prior to transmission on USB.  To understand what it actually does, you need documentation or try reverse engineering.

Comment: What did you install on your PC to use this camera?  If you had to install a proprietary USB driver or application program, then essentially it's a closed system.  That is, the camera end can compress the image(s), transmit by USB, and then the PC host can decompress and present a raw image.  As a closed system, the inner workings of the transfer (other than USB is involved) do not have to be revealed.

Comment: @sawdust I had to install their propietary software, yes. The camera is not registered at /dev/video0. The thing is, if the images are compressed to be transmited, using a lossy format, why decompress them? Why not store them compressed to save disk space? Are there lossless formats with such a compression ratio (30 to 1)?

Comment: *"The camera is not registered at /dev/video0"* -- Plug the camera into the host USB port, and then use the `dmesg` command to dump the system log.  The last eight or so messages should be for the (a) the low-level USB connection, (b) the driver that is registered to interact with the camera device, and (c) a report of the device name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, cameras make demosaicing by using the camera's built-in firmware, and transmiting a compressed format like h.264, Mjpeg or others. Assuming that some  professional and advanced cameras allow you to request the RAW image (normally in YUV format) and the output of digital sensors is almost always between 10 and 14-bit per-component on a linear scale, the numbers will be different...

So, assuming a YUV output and assuming an ADC of 10bits as mentioned in the documentation, the bandwith would be something like this in RAW:

```
1280 x 1024 x 10 (bits/pxl in a YUV 4:2:2) x 1 (channel - Sensor/wBayer Filters) x 23 x 1/8*10⁶= ~38 MB/s.
```

You can find a good information about this in the next link:
https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/fov.html

But related to your last comment:

> I got a value of ~4 MiB/s.

Probably there is some kind of compression.

For example for the rPi camera, using V4L driver, you can request the modes it works, and the fps options in each mode:

> [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x11ccc50] Compressed:       mjpeg :
> Motion-JPEG : 1920x1080 1280x720 800x600 640x480 640x360 352x288
> 320x240 1920x1080 [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x11ccc50] Raw       :
> yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : 640x480 800x600 640x360 352x288
> 320x240 640x480

Cheers.

Comment: @KAE yes. Sorry for the typo and thanks for the correction.